# Como excluir um chat irrelevante?

Tags: suporte

Gostaria de saber se seria possível a exclusão do seguinte chat:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27463/discussion-between-dorival-zanetto-and-diego-souza

O mesmo foi criado para atender uma dúvida bem especifica, que por sinal foi resolvida segundo o autor da pergunta (via e-mail) e não publicada no Stack Overflow.

Pois bem, o que me incomoda é o fato de que o chat possui indexação no Google e está vinculado ao meu nome e como solicitei a exclusão da minha conta gostaria que fosse removido junto.

Se puderem fazer algo, serei muito grato.

Comment: Aparentemente [ele é excluído sozinho](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5067/20615). não tenho como dar mais detalhes, mas um moderador irá poder te ajudar mais do que eu

Comment: De uma maneira geral conteúdos não são excluídos, não sei se chat é possível, pode ser, mas se ele for temporário duvido que será indexado. O que pode ser feito é desvincular o conteúdo gerado por você da sua conta ou, até a sua própria conta. O que acho lamentável. Você parece ser um usuário de boas contribuições.

Comment: Relacionado: [Sobre criação e remoção de salas de chat](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5066/7210)

Comment: Primeiramente, gostaria de agradecer de uma maneira geral a todos pela atenção e ajuda que têm prestado nesses últimos dias para resolução dos pontos que tenho apresentado, tanto via Stackoverflow quanto por outros meios, em relação a remoção da conta acredito que não será mais necessária. Sendo assim, gostaria de saber; Preciso preencher novamente o formulário de contato cancelando a exclusão? (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact), mais uma vez, muito obrigado a todos pela atenção!

Comment: @DorivalZanetto Acredito que não, só tirando o DELETE ME já resolve. Legal continuar por aqui.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A sala foi excluída.

Aproveitando, que tal repensar a decisão de excluir sua conta? É sempre chato perder usuários com boa participação...

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda @bfavaretto, a sala não está aparecendo mais. Sobre a questão de exclusão da conta re-pensei e achei algumas alternativas para não precisar exclui-la. Mais uma vez, muito obrigado!

Comment: @DorivalZanetto Esses links são de outra sala de chat, não da que eu excluí (e que você tinha linkado na pergunta).

Comment: @bfavaretto você poderia excluir duas salas em que estou? https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/101908 e https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/101912 pois as mesmas foram criadas para informações específicas, e estão indexadas no Google. Tenho o mesmo desejo.